# String output adjustments to serve in form of array // -NODE JS-

Tags: arrays, node.js, undefined

This is my current string in a variable, of which is derived from jquery using the cheerio npm:

```
281737.0886737347096
281737.0886737348482
281737.0886737351833
281737.0886737351840
281737.0886737351857
281737.0886737355763
281737.0886737361528
281737.0886737361535
281737.0886737361580
undefined
undefined
```

I need it so that an array is created with each unique number in its own index: such as 
`array = [281737.0886737347096,281737.0886737348482,etc]`

Such that:

```
array[0] {when called}  = 281737.0886737347096
```

And therefore, wanting to remove the any "undefined" elements from the final array.

I have tried this:

```
var array  = []
array.push(unique) #unique numbers of string pushed into array
array= array.filter(function(a){return typeof a !== 'undefined';});
```

However, it returns nothing when array is logged back to console.

Comment: Please elaborate what you're trying to do.

Comment: @vibhor1997a I  did: I need it so that an array is created with each unique number in its own index: such as  array = [281737.0886737347096,281737.0886737348482,etc] without the "undefined"

Comment: hey, does the strung contain repetive values?

Comment: no apart from the undefined maybe?

Answer (score 0):

I did't get you but I think you want to do this:-

```js
let s = `281737.0886737347096
281737.0886737348482
281737.0886737351833
281737.0886737351840
281737.0886737351857
281737.0886737355763
281737.0886737361528
281737.0886737361535
281737.0886737361580
undefined
undefined`;

let o = s.split('\n').filter(e => e).reduce((acc, cv, i) => {
    acc[cv] = i + 1;
    return acc;
}, {});
let arr = Object.keys(o);
arr = arr.filter(x => x !== "undefined");
console.log(arr);
```

**Edit**

We have to deal with the strings instead of Number due to inconsistent 64-bit floating point representation in this case.

Comment: Hi, I tried this with my variable string and I get this [ 281737.0886737347 ]
`[ 281737.08867373486 ]
[ 281737.0886737352 ]
[ 281737.0886737352 ]
[ 281737.0886737352 ]
[ 281737.08867373556 ]
[ 281737.08867373614 ]
[ 281737.08867373614 ]
[ 281737.08867373614 ]`

Comment: Still same issue: When I call arr[0] it gives all of the values instead of 281737.0886737347096. However you did manage to get rid of "undefined".

Comment: Same thing mate ; [link](http://prntscr.com/jzj3yp) this is what is logged

Comment: But it is working in the `stack snippet` demo. Are you doing the same thing?

Comment: IT is working in stack snippet, however, I think the string that I have [from jquery cheerio] is slightly different even though it looks the same in console.log? Like this, [link](http://prntscr.com/jzj96w). How can I show you the raw string? Because the logged one looks like \n through it however, it seems like the method in which you are tackling does not work, maybe there is something different?